# Access Google Drive through Web app

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I just dive into Google Drive APIs. And I have a problem.
I have to make small project for some group of users, which access **MY OWN** google drive and interact with files: request, update, delete. The problem is that i cannot setup that project because there is always redirect to Google prompt page. But why I have to authorize **my own** requests if I had already specified  it in source code (client_id and client_secret). What i have to do or what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Tokens are short lived -- 1 hour by default.  It's probably expiring.  You can request a `Refresh Token`, which has a sliding expiration of 14 days.

Comment: no, i need persistent connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a service account if you don't wish to have to authenticate everytime.

You can find the information you need about service accounts/service account-auth here;

https://developers.google.com/drive/service-accounts

Make sure when doing service account auth that you pass the `prn` parameter to make the account pretend to be you (so it can access your Google Drive).

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount#formingclaimset